# When reviewing using tabbed browsing, clicking "Close" doesn't always work

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

When reviewing whether a question should be closed, sometimes the close button does not work.

The following has happened to me a couple of times now:

1. Click on review.
2. See that there is one post by a new user and one post with close votes.  Open both in new tabs.
3. Go to the tab with the post by the new user.  See that it should be closed.  Leave a comment for the user, vote to close it, and mark the editing task as completed.
4. Close that browser tab and open the other.  Discover it's the question you just voted to close.  Click <kbd>Close</kbd>; the site displays a message saying that you already closed the question and giving the offer to retract the close vote.

Instead of offering to retract the close vote, the system should inform you that your review has already completed successfully.

Note that if you vote to close in the first tab, it doesn't actually count toward your total number of Close reviews. One of two things should thus also be changed. Either: (1) the close vote should count toward your total number of close votes or else (2) in all situations where it's possible to act on the same post in multiple review threads (such as First Posts and Late Answers or such as close-voting anywhere before going to the Close review), only the first action should count.

Comment: What's your browser? Version? Any other specifics?

Comment: @tbodt, I don't think the issue is browser-specific, but FWIW I'm running the latest Chrome on OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: This same issue also occurs using the "delete" link and the Low Quality queue - clicking the delete link in one window and then the delete button in the other will result in the "You've already voted to delete this..." message